# Sidebar toggle button not showing 3 bars while viewing in mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, adminlte

While I open a page in mobile, the sidebar toggle is not looking like a menu, it is looking like a box. I'm using the adminlte theme.

[image: side toggle button]

Code:

```
<a href="#" class="sidebar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" role="button">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</a>
```

Comment: have you seen the console window is there any error when you are doing the mobile view.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your mobile phone isn't supporting the font type that you have or maybe it is not installed in the phone, please review into the font support and the version of your mobile's browser.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening as your design is responsive . If you will open the same in web and increase the zoom level in the browser option  , you will get the same issue . According to the screen size the design changes in such kind of designs . Show to avoid these issues try to use "adaptive design" which might be difficult but can solve your issues .